# Subconscious & Vipassana

Tags: insight

Is the subconscious what becomes conscious when insight occurs? When the hinderances fall is the subconscious seen? What is the subconscious in relationship to the scriptures & the Abhidhamma?

Related to this question: [Cravings Arising to Consciousness](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/35689/151)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best descriptions of the structure of consciousness from a Abhidhamma standpoint is found in Lama Govinda's '***The Psychological Attitude of Early Buddhist Philosophy***" pdf page 121. Recommend the entire book, as a user friendly account of the Higher Doctrine of the Buddha i.e. Abhidhamma.

Answer (score 0):

From the viewpoint of modern Western psychology, the 'subconscious' is explained as follows:

> *The subconscious is the part of our mind that is not in current awareness. It is the part of our consciousness that is not being
> focused on and is lying dormant. It is impossible to hold the entirety
> of our knowledge in direct focus in our minds at the same time so we
> need to store memories and knowledge. This storage is known as the
> subconscious, the term being coined by Pierre Janet. The subconscious
> stores all of your memories, beliefs, previous experiences, the
> people/places you have seen, and the skills you have acquired.
> Information in the subconscious cannot be recalled easily, they are
> buried deep within our minds (or repressed).*
>
> *https://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Subconscious*

The closest Pali term to 'subconscious' is '[anusaya](https://suttacentral.net/define/anusaya)' or 'underlying tendencies', as follows:

> *Mendicants, there are these seven underlying tendencies. What seven? The underlying tendencies of sensual desire, repulsion, views, doubt, conceit, desire for becoming and ignorance. These are the seven underlying tendencies.*
>
> [*AN 7.11*](https://suttacentral.net/an7.11/en/sujato)

'*Anusaya*' can flow out or erupt from the subconscious into consciousness. This '*outflow*' or '*eruption*' in Pali is called '[asava](https://suttacentral.net/define/%C4%81sava)'. The product or result of these anusaya flowing out are called '*hindrances*' ('[nivarana](https://suttacentral.net/define/n%C4%ABvara%E1%B9%87a)').

Therefore, on a gross level, it appears it is the hindrances themselves which are the '*subconscious*' coming into consciousness.

When the hindrances end, what occurs is the bliss & equanimity of jhana; which is obviously not '*the subconscious*' referred to by modern Western psychology.

However, on a very subtle level, when a jhana attainer recollects their '*previous dwellings*', '*past ego adherences*' or '*pubbenivāsa*' (described in [SN 22.79](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.79/en/bodhi)), this appears to be an example of genuine insight (*vipassana*) in relation to the 'subconscious'.

Answer (score -1):

No.  It is a bit like saying what happens to your liver or kidney when insight occurs?  The subconscious is just something that keeps your consciousness moving along.  It might be in the right direction or it might be the wrong direction.  You only know when it's too late.